# How can I handle raw bytes on dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm totally new at app developing.

I trying to communicate with C-written end device via raw UDP packet. (such a modbus-like protocol)
And I'm suffering pain with serial/deserializing class(struct).

Here is a simple class, `Packet` which contain `uint32, uint16, uint8`.

1. `Pack()` is working, but are there any better way to achieve that?
2. I don't know how can I implement `Unpack()` method. I mean, how can I convert `Uint8List` to `int`?

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  var pkt = new Packet();
  pkt.TID = 0x01234567;
  pkt.Src = 0x89;
  pkt.Des = 0xab;
  pkt.Data = 0xcdef;
  var buf = pkt.Pack();

  print('Packed: ${buf}');

  var pkt_2 = new Packet();
  if (pkt_2.Unpack(buf) != null) {
    print("panic!");
    return;
  }
  print('UnPacked: ${pkt_2.toString()}');
}

class Packet {
  int TID; // uint32
  int Src; // uint8
  int Des; // uint8
  int Data; //  uint16

  static const SIZE = 8;

  String toString() {
    return 'TID: ${TID.toRadixString(16)}, Src:${Src.toRadixString(16)}, Des:${Des.toRadixString(16)}, Data:${Data.toRadixString(16)}';
  }

  Uint8List Pack() {
    var buf = Byteconv.itou32(TID) +
        Byteconv.itou8(Src) +
        Byteconv.itou8(Des) +
        Byteconv.itou16(Data);

    return Uint8List.fromList(buf);
  }

  Error Unpack(Uint8List buf) {
    if (buf.length != SIZE) {
      return Error();
    }

    // What can I do?
    // TID =
    // Src =
    // Des =
    // Data =

    return null;
  }
}

class Byteconv {
  static Uint8List itou64(int val) {
    return Uint8List(8)..buffer.asByteData().setUint64(0, val, Endian.big);
  }

  static Uint8List itou32(int val) {
    return Uint8List(4)..buffer.asByteData().setUint32(0, val, Endian.big);
  }

  static Uint8List itou16(int val) {
    return Uint8List(2)..buffer.asByteData().setUint16(0, val, Endian.big);
  }

  static Uint8List itou8(int u8) {
    return Uint8List(1)..buffer.asUint8List()[0] = u8;
  }
}
```

SOLVED

```dart
    var buf_view = ByteData.sublistView(buf);
    TID = buf_view.getUint32(0);
    Src = buf_view.getUint8(4);
    Des = buf_view.getUint8(5);
    Data = buf_view.getUint16(6);
```

Comment: You already know about `ByteData.setUint32`, etc. Does `ByteData.getUint32`, etc. not do what you want?

Comment: thank you a lot.

I fixed like below and it works.
```dart
    var buf_view = ByteData.sublistView(buf);
    TID = buf_view.getUint32(0);
    Src = buf_view.getUint8(4);
    Des = buf_view.getUint8(5);
    Data = buf_view.getUint16(6);
```